# how to find derivative of an equation of matrices with element-wise multiplication or division

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, formatting, algebraic-manipulation, ncalgebra

For an equation like this:

$$ M= \left(\begin{array}{c} A\:x-B \otimes y\end{array}\right) \oslash C $$

where $\otimes$ is an element-wise multiplication and $\oslash$ is an element-wise division.

A, B and C are real matrices with ($n \times m$), ($n \times k$) and ($n \times k$), respectively.

Whereas, x and y are vectors with ($m \times 1$) and ($n \times 1$), respectively.

**I need to find the derivative of $M$ with respect to the vector $x$.**

Is "NCAlgebra package" is the right tool for me? and if so, how to type element-wise multiplication or division in NCAlgebra.

***Edit to eliminate confusion:***
the symbols $\otimes$ and $\oslash$ represents the Hadamard product and division  which are built into certain programming languages under various names. Sometimes its called broadcast multiplication or array multiplication [see this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#In_programming_languages)

Comment: That does not make sense. $A \,x$ is a $(n \times 1)$-vector; how do you divide that by $C$? Moreover, the dimensions of $B$ and $y$ are not the same. So how do you multiply elementwise?

Comment: Hi Henrik,
I think there is a little bit of confusing here. For instant, B and y dimensions do not have to be the same to multiply them element-wise. try this this pseudo code in matlab: n = 4;
m = 3;
k = 2;

A =sym('A', [n m]);
B =sym('B', [n k]);
C=sym('C', [n k]);
x=sym('x', [m 1]);
y=sym('y', [n 1]);

M = (A*x-B.*y)./(C)

Comment: How does that subtraction in the parens work? It seems the two quantities are not of comparable dimension.

Comment: Hi Daniel, check out how using the provided matlab code before. [see the results of your question here ](https://imgur.com/js0nRc3)

Comment: (1) Take derivative of `A.x`. (2) Extend dimension from `m x 1` to `m x k` by making `k` copies and stacking horizontally. (2) Divide `j`th copy element-wise by column `j` of `C`.